# Trouble compiling c++ program with "curses.h"

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, header-files

I'm testing a program I saw on here for arrow key reading in c++. It used a library called "conio.h" but since I'm on a macOS, I replaced it with "curses.h" because I heard it was similar. It had the same function I needed (`getch()`), but when I went to compile it using `g++ test.cpp` it threw the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _main in test-9fc81b.o
  "_wgetch", referenced from:
      _main in test-9fc81b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What may be the issue? It's something to do with non-standard libraries. I traced back the error to within the header file, where it calls `wgetch()` and `stdscr()` as seen above.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c, ex;

    while(1)
    {
        c = getch();

        if (c && c != 224)
        {
            cout << endl << "Not arrow: " << (char) c << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            switch(ex = getch())
            {
                case KEY_UP     /* H */:
                    cout << endl << "Up" << endl;//key up
                    break;
                case KEY_DOWN   /* K */:
                    cout << endl << "Down" << endl;   // key down
                    break;
                case KEY_LEFT   /* M */:
                    cout << endl << "Left" << endl;  // key left
                    break;
                case KEY_RIGHT: /* P */
                    cout << endl << "Right" << endl;  // key right
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << endl << (char) ex << endl;  // not arrow
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you `-lcurses` when linking?

Comment: `Curses` is a package with a header and library.  You should include the header (done) and link with the library (not done).  You need to install the Curses package for your development environment, if it exists.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: Here's something to think about. Just because two libraries have functions with the same name does not mean that the function in one library works the same as the function in the other library. There's no reason to think that a program written specifically for Windows will work on the Mac. Suggest you find some other example to learn C++ from.

Comment: That's a good point. curses requires a few things to be initialized properly, none of this happens in the shown code. Translating a program to a different operating system isn't as simple as replacing header files. C++ is just too complicated, for that to be the case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yea I'm starting to realise that now. Curses.h is already installed on my laptop by default. I traced back the error to within the header file itself. Guess it was dangerous to assume the pre-installed libraries were "ready to go".

Answer (score 1):

@Eljay was right. The solution to compiling with curses.h is to pass the following flag as well as such:

```
g++ -lcurses test.cpp
```

Outputting your executable a.out

Comment: The question does tag, `Makefile`, it may be good to expand the answer with a modification to a makefile or remove the tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).